# If $A$ is a vector space over $Q$, $Ext_{R}^{n}(C,A)$ is a vector space over $Q$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

Let $R$ be a domain with fraction field $Q$, and let $A$, $C$ be $R$-modules. Then, if $A$ is a vector space over $Q$, $Ext_{R}^{n}(C,A)$ is a vector space over $Q$.

Let $0\rightarrow A\xrightarrow{\eta}E^0\xrightarrow{d^0}E^1\xrightarrow{d^1}E^2\rightarrow\cdots$ be an injective resolution. Then, by definition, $Ext_{R}^{n}(C,A)=\mathrm{ker}\  d^{n}_{*}/\mathrm{im}\ d^{n-1}_{*}$, where $d^{n}_{*} : Hom_{R}(C,E^n)\rightarrow Hom_{R}(C,E^{n+1})$.

I guess $Hom_{R}(C,E^n)$ should be a vector space over $Q$ but I am not sure.

Comment: You should rather use a projective resolution of $C$.

Comment: I see. I guess that's because two ways give the canonical isomorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is a bit sloppy: $A$ should not be just a $Q$-vector space, but rather it should be a $Q$-vector space so inducing the structure of $R$-module.

You should rather use a projective resolution of $C$, because if $M$ is any $R$-module, you can give $\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,A)$ a structure of $Q$-vector space which is functorial: if $M\to N$ is a morphism of $R$-modules, then the induced map $\operatorname{Hom}_R(N,A)\to\operatorname{Hom}_R(M,A)$ is a morphism of $Q$-vector spaces.

Comment: For your first sentence : you are correct that it is a bit sloppy, although given an $R$-module $A$, there is at most one way for it to be a $Q$-vector space , so "$A$ is a $Q$-vector space" is a perfectly valid property if $A$ is known to be an $R$-module

Comment: @Max There is at most one way for it to be a $Q$-vector space if we prescribe that the action of $R$ is the same.

Comment: Yes but if $A$ *is* an $R$-module (not its underlying set, or its underlying abelian group), the sentence "a $Q$-vector space structure on $A$" is inambiguous, because $A$ contains the data of the $R$-structure